# Библиотека для работы с русским языком c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть массив русских букв. Нужно работать с элементами этого массива, также как и с обычными английскими буквами. 
Не могу найти способ обрабатывать русские символы.

```
char rus=['а',  'б'...]
```

Выдает ошибку, т.к. русские символы это то ли строка, то ли еще что-то.

Comment: Работайте с символами как с `wchar_t`

Comment: @aleks.andr это увеличенный char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, ваш исходник в кодировке типа UTF-8, так что русские буквы состоят из нескольких байт. В зависимости от требований программы можно перейти на однобайтное кодирование типа cp1251, а можно использовать символьный тип `wchar_t` или там `char32_t` или `char16_t` - словом, многобайтные.

Пока, по вопросу судя, думаю, что вам будет достаточно однобайтной кодировки, так что попробуйте для начала сохранять исходник *не* как utf-8.